# C++ Question mark character

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I have a question, please:

```
output_samples = opus_decode(dec, lost ? NULL : data[toggle], len[toggle], out, max_frame_size, 0);
```

Does this mean:

If lost is 1, use NULL.
If lost is 0, use data[toggle]

?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes. (Technically it tests if lost is `true`, but `1` can be implicitly converted to `true`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to be more specific, whenever `lost` is any non-zero value, the expression will evaluate to `NULL`. Else, it will evaluate to `data[toggle]`.

Comment: Technically speaking, the expression *evaluates to* NULL or data[toggle]; it *does not* return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ?: pair define the conditional operator, also known as ternary operator.  And your interpretation is correct.